# Diferença entre mudar um variável e um objeto em recursão

Tags: java, recursão, java-8

Estou fazendo recursão em duas situações: uma altera um campo do objeto e outra altera diretamente a *string*. Qual a diferença entre essas duas formas de retorno já que dá resultado diferente?

```
public class Person {
    String fname = "f";
    String lname = "Doe";
    int age = 24;

  public static  String mudaNome(String nome){
    if(!nome.equals("fiii")){
      nome = nome + "i";
      System.out.println("name1: " +nome);
      mudaNome(nome);
    }
    System.out.println("name1 output: " +nome);

   return nome;
}

public static Person mudaNomeObj(Person myObj){
    if(!myObj.fname.equals("fiii")){
      myObj.fname = myObj.fname + "i";
          System.out.println("name2 : " +myObj.fname);
      mudaNomeObj(myObj);
    }
    System.out.println("name2 output: " +myObj.fname);

  return myObj;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   Person myObj = new Person();

   System.out.println("name1 final output:" +mudaNome(myObj.fname));

   System.out.println("---------------");

   Person myObj2 = new Person();
   System.out.println("name2 final output:" + mudaNomeObj(myObj2).fname);
 }
}
```

Saída:

> ```
> name1: fi
> name1: fii
> name1: fiii
> name1 output: fiii
> name1 output: fiii
> name1 output: fii
> name1 output: fi
> name1 final output:fi
> ---------------
> name2 : fi
> name2 : fii
> name2 : fiii
> name2 output: fiii
> name2 output: fiii
> name2 output: fiii
> name2 output: fiii
> name2 final output:fiii
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A diferença é justamente a variável local e o campo que é usado no retorno.

O segundo exemplo retorna no final o campo do objeto. Cada execução da função muda o campo. O campo não é local, ele pertence ao objeto então toda mudança que a função faz nele é preservado, por isso no final quando retorna o campo pega o estado da última alteração.

Uma variável local só existe no contexto daquela função no momento que ela está executando, portanto ao fim da sua execução ela é descartada e só sobrevive um valor que é retornado no final.

No primeiro exemplo o retorno é apenas o resultado dado na primeira execução da função, todas as outras são descartadas. O motivo do descarte é que o retorno não é usado em nenhum contexto da função, perceba é chamado `mudaNome(nome)` e nada é guardado, então a recursão toda é desperdiçada a não ser pelo fato de estar imprimindo algo, que provavelmente está aí para fins de depuração, se tirar isso a recursão está servindo para nada.

Se guardar o dado retornado e usá-lo aí mantém estado, apesar de uma forma bem ineficiente de fazer. Ou nem precisa da variável, talvez o que queria era:

```
class Person {
    String fname = "f";
    String lname = "Doe";
    int age = 24;

    public static String mudaNome(String nome) {
        if (!nome.equals("fiii")) nome = mudaNome(nome + "i");
        return nome;
    }

    public static Person mudaNomeObj(Person myObj) {
        if (!myObj.fname.equals("fiii")) {
            myObj.fname += "i";
            mudaNomeObj(myObj);
        }
        return myObj;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Person myObj = new Person();
       System.out.println("name1 final output: " + mudaNome(myObj.fname));
       System.out.println("---------------");
       Person myObj2 = new Person();
       System.out.println("name2 final output: " + mudaNomeObj(myObj2).fname);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MpgPya). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/VariableRecursionjava). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Method/VariableRecursion.java).

Comment: Great. Thank you, bro!