# Constante usada dentro de laço de repetição

Tags: javascript, lógica

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const divElement = document.createElement("div");

divElement.setAttribute("id", "resultado");
body.appendChild(divElement);

for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    const textElement = document.createElement("p");
    textElement.innerHTML = "Resultado: " + i;
    divElement.append(textElement);
}
```

O que acontece exatamente dentro do `for` com a `const textElement`? (O código funciona normalmente, mas queria saber o que está acontecendo ali com aquela constante)

- É criada um `array` com 20 posições `(textElement[1], textElement[2]... textElement[n])`?
- A `constante` é sobrescrita?
- A cada laço é obtido um novo valor?
- Se não for nenhuma das causas acima, o que acontece então?

Referências: [Alura](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/entenda-diferenca-entre-var-let-e-const-no-javascript), [Wiki](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constante_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

Comment: A constante esta dentro do escopo do for, ou seja, somente vai existir a constante na iteração corrente e no próximo ciclo vai ser declarada novamente a constante, pq ai será outro escopo de iteração.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> É criada um array com 20 posições (textElement[1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364635/101), textElement[2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101)... textElement[n])?

Não, você deve estar confundindo o que este objeto é. Ele é um manipulador do [DOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101), sequer é o DOM, então ele tem uma forma para se referir a um elemento do DOM, só isso, não tem *array* ou qualquer outro valor do seu código. Podemos dizer que é uma espécie de *proxy* ao DOM.

> A constante é sobrescrita?

Em cada execução um objeto constante novo é criado, a constante é a mesma. [Leia isso para entender melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364635/101).

> A cada laço é obtido um novo valor?

Sim, claro que pode ser o mesmo valor, mas um novo objeto.

> Se não for nenhuma das causas acima, o que acontece então?

O problema de como manipular o DOM é do *engine* do JavaScript. No momento que usar o `innerHTML` algo acontecerá no DOM, mas não é problema seu. Quando pegar um novo objeto ele apresentará o estado do DOM no momento incluindo o que já foi alterado. O DOM é obviamente mutável. Você não tem acesso a ele diretamente, só através desses objetos manipuladores, ele é detalhe de implementação.

Comment: Então esse laço possui cerca de 20 objetos? Caso não fosse um objeto, e sim apenas um valor como `const a = 10`, seria a mesma resposta da pergunta (no caso criaria 20 constantes com 20 valores iguais, no caso 10?)

Comment: Não, existe só um DOM, ele cria 20 objeto para manipular o DOM. Mas cada um deles será descartado no final do passo do laço. Se fosse outra coisa, o resultado seria outro. Por incrível que pareça é muito parecido com isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/419022/101. O que está fazendo é manipular o objeto que você não tem controle no seu algoritmo. Se passar fazer em uma variável local tudo muda, e aí você terá que armazenar em uma variável. Vou tentar achar uma pergunta que mostra que variável criada dentro do laço só existe enquanto o passo está executando, em outro passo já é outra let/const